# How to get the underscore function _.first to work on the arguments objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

As part of the precourse for a coding bootcamp, we have to create a simpler version of the underscore JS library. I am struggling with creating the **_.first function**, which:

- Returns an array with the first n elements of an array.
- If n is not provided it returns an array with just the first element.

This is what I've got so far:

```
_.first = function(array, n) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return [];
  if (typeof n != "number" || n <= 0) return [].slice.call(array, 0, 1);
  return n >= array.length ? array : [].slice.call(array, 0, n);
};
```

It passes all test except one: "It must work on an arguments object"
I know the arguments object passes an array with all the arguments passed and it has a length property but Im struggling to work with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arguments` object is just that, a variable defined implicitly on each function scope that acts like an array. Has a `length` property and you can access the elements by using number properties like a normal array:

```js
var _ = {};

_.first = function() {
  if (arguments.length == 0) { // If there's no arguments
      return [];
  } else { // When there's 1 or more arguments
      var array = arguments[0];
      var n = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : 1; // If there's only the "array" argument ("n" is not provided), set "n" to 1
      // And now your code, which has nice checks just in case the values are invalid
      if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
          return [];
      }
      if (typeof n != "number" || n <= 0) {
          n = 1;
      }
      return [].slice.call(array, 0, n); // Don't worry if slice is bigger than the array length. It will just work, and also always return a copy of the array instead of the array itself.
  }
};

console.log( _.first() );
console.log( _.first([0,1,2]) );
console.log( _.first([0,1,2], 2) );
console.log( _.first([0,1,2], 10) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add something to the first answer. The arguments object is something that is normally created implicitly by JavaScript and made available inside the function body. In order to write a unit test for "It must work on an arguments object", they must explicitly define an arguments object and pass it in. This is a bad unit test because it is testing the internal working of your function. You should be free to write the function any way you like, and a unit test should test the external behaviour of the function (return value and/or side effects, based on the arguments passed).

So imo your original solution is good and the test is designed to force you to use a certain syntax for the sake of learning, but this is misleading.